# Monerod not syncing past ~1200700 in TAILS - Segmentation fault

Tags: monerod, linux, tor

I have been unsuccessfully trying to sync the blockchain for the past 5 days using the latest 32bit Linux Monero Core on Tails live USB. I followed the instructions in the Tails/Tor post on /r/Monero to the letter and everything works until it reaches around 1200700 blocks then I keep getting 'Segmentation fault' message. I tried placing the data directory on different HDD's and SSD's and keep encountering the same problem. Would greatly appreciate any help as I'd love to have a node running and support the Monero community.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your monerod to the latest version 0.10.1.0 Wolfram Warptangent.

There has been a hard fork to introduce RingCT transactions at [block 1220517](http://moneroblocks.info/block/1220517) and if you are running an old version, it will not be able to sync with the network.

Comment: I'm already running on the 32bit Linux 0.10.1.0 Wolfram Warptangent which is giving me the 'segmentation fault' error messages. Are there any known issues with using this and Tails OS / Tor configuration?

Comment: Strange, that error should occur only with a version conflict. Maybe you submit a bug report for the 32 bit version?